# Как показывать hint у combobox при перемещении в выпавшем списке элементов выбора?

Tags: delphi, combobox

Есть combobox со списком элементов. У каждого из них в коллекции Objects имеется некоторое описание. Как показывать это описание в виде hint'a при перемещении по элементам списка? Есть ли у компонента combobox событие, которое происходит при перемещении в выпавшем списке?
Спасибо.

Comment: возможно, вам нужен [`CBN_SELCHANGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775821(v=vs.85).aspx)? Хотя возможно это оповещение непосредственно о смене значения.

Comment: teran, почитал я про этот CBN_SELCHANGE notification code. Только не понял, как его применить. Вот пользователь открыл список для выбора и перемещением мыши изменяет элементы списка (еще не кликает для подтверждения своего выбора). При этом активный элемент перемещается. Где я должен написать свой код по смене hint'a?

Comment: `CBN_SELCHANGE` это не то. [вот, кстати, аналогичный вашему вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32474801/1216425)

Answer (score 0):

На основании найденной ссылки [на аналогичный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32474801/1216425), можно применить следующий подход. Однако, насколько я понял, это требует ручной отрисовки элементов комбобокса.
В общем и целом, необходимо обработать сообщение [`WM_DRAWITEM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775923%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), параметром которого является структура [`DRAWITEMSTRUCT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775802%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) или для delphi - 
`TDrawItemStruct`.

*Мой ответ не полностью соответствует вопросу, но показывает что-то приближенное. Тут простейший вывод элементов комбобокса, и вместо хинта текущий элемент над которым находится мышь добавляется в `TMemo`.*

Итак для перехвата сообщения `WM_DRAWITEM` добавляем в класс формы соответствующий метод. Также необходимо установить `Style` компонента в `OwnerDraw`, иначе данное сообщение мы получать не будем.

```
private
  procedure wmDrawItem(var msg : TWMDrawItem); message WM_DRAWITEM;
```

и переходим к его реализации (комбобокс имеет `name = testComboBox`):

```
procedure TTestForm.wmDrawItem(var msg: TWMDrawItem);
var item : string;
begin
    if(msg.DrawItemStruct.hwndItem = testComboBox.Handle) then begin

        item := testComboBox.Items[msg.DrawItemStruct.itemID];

        TextOut(msg.DrawItemStruct.hDC,
                msg.DrawItemStruct.rcItem.Left,
                msg.DrawItemStruct.rcItem.Top,
                PWideChar(item),
                length(item));

        if(msg.DrawItemStruct.itemAction = ODA_SELECT) then begin
            if(msg.DrawItemStruct.itemState = ODS_SELECTED) then begin
                memo1.Lines.Add(item);
            end;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Здесь сначала проверяется, что сообщение прислано искомому комбобоксу. Затем надо отрисовать пункт меню. Для этого мы вытаскиваем текущий элемент `item`. Это мы делаем всегда, для любого пункта (т.е. меню рисуем вручную, это  тема для отдельного вопроса). В данном случае элементарный `TextOut`.

Далее уже непосредственная проверка `itemAction` и `itemState` структуры, о которых можно почитать по ссылке, приведенной выше.

В результате работы данного кода при перемещении указателя мыши над элементами выпадающего меню текущий пункт добавляется в `memo1`.

*Ответ не претендует на корректность кода, а только демонстрирует подход к решению задачи*

В принципе, наверное, тот же код можно реализовать с помощью события `OnDrawItem`.